# How can I get value of html element in sap ui5 xml view

Tags: google-maps, xhtml, sapui5

I'm trying to do [google maps api example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) for sap ui5 and the following is my xml view:

```
    <html:input id="pac_input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location" />
    <html:div id="type_selector" class="controls">
        <html:input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked" />
        <html:label for="changetype_all">All</html:label>

        <html:input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype_establishment" />
        <html:label for="changetype_establishment">Establishments</html:label>

        <html:input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype_address" />
        <html:label for="changetype_address">Addresses</html:label>

        <html:input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype_geocode" />
        <html:label for="changetype_geocode">Geocodes</html:label>
    </html:div>
    <html:div id="map-canvas" class="myMap"></html:div>
```

I want to get "pac_input" input and "type_selector" div by Id in controller.js. But whenever I try this.getView().byId("map_canvas") it says ***this.getView is not a function***
and I guess it happens because **this** is a Window object and I don't know how I can get elements. I will be very glad for helps. Here my controller.js :

```
onAfterRendering: function() {  
    if (!this.initialized) {  
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
            this.initialized = true;  
            util.Common.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
            util.Common.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var mapOptions = {  
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),  
                zoom: 8,  
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
            };  
            util.Common.googlemap = new google.maps.Map(this.getView().byId("map_canvas").getDomRef(),  
                mapOptions); 
            var input = this.getView().byId("pac_input");
            var types = this.getView().byId("type_selector");
            ...
```

Update 1: I tried also to reach via sap.ui.getCore.byId() but still it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I made a mistake at `<html:div id="map-canvas" class="myMap"></html:div>.` The id should be map_canvas. And I embeded the div element to a variable at common place and overwrite it at onInit(). Now it works.

```
onInit : function () {
    ...
    util.Common.map_canvas_div = this.getView().byId("map_canvas");
    ...
}
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var input = util.Common.pac_input_input;
    ...
}
```